# Vim is slow when editing files over samba

Tags: performance, vim, vmware, samba

I have a windows host running ubuntu in vmware.  I set up ubuntu to export a samba share so that I could use gvim on windows.  When editing files over this connection visual mode gets really slow.  I have also noticed bufexplorer gets slow during this time too.  Neither of these are slow when I am editing files on the windows host.

What can I do to improve performance?

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I would try is setting the `directory` option (see :help directory) to a local directory.  That way all the swap file operations won't go over the network.

Comment: I have both directory and backup already set so that they do not go over the samba drive.